# Is there a dask equivalent to maxtasksperchild?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

We have jobs which interact with native code and there are unavoidable memory leaks while the worker is processing the task. The simple solution for our problems has been to restart the worker after a specified number of tasks.

We are migrating from python's multiprocessing which has a useful *maxtasksperchild* option which closes down the workers after a specified number of tasks.

Is there something built-in in dask that is comparable to *maxtasksperchild*?

As a workaround, we are keeping track of the workers who have completed a task by appending their worker address to the result payload and calling *retire_workers* on the client side manually.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just start the worker with a memory limit and let it restart by itself once it's overloaded? [Here](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/worker.html#memory-management)'s more info about worker memory managment

Comment: A memory limit could technically work if dask handled worker recycling between task execute boundaries. But from our experience, dask will kill a worker whenever the memory limit is exceeded, which is inconvenient because the task will need to be restarted (and sometimes fail unexpectedly depending on the retries parameter).

Comment: The most common use case we have is that we want workers to execute exactly one task and then recycle.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such equivalent in Dask